# Join to large parquet tables located on S3; output to S3 again

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking for the most cost effective option to join two `parquet tables` that reside on S3 and write the result back to S3

`table_a` is about 10.5 TiB in size and structured like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| id    | name  |
+-------+-------+
|      1|      a|
|      1|      b|
|      2|      a|
|      2|      d|
```

`table_b` is 200 GiB in size and structured like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| name  | id    |
+-------+-------+
|      a|      1|
|      b|      2|
|      c|      3|
|      d|      4|
```

now I want to do a join with these two tables some generic SQL here:

```
CREATE TABLE table_c as 
(SELECT * FROM table_a LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON
(table_a.name = table_b.name) DROP COLUMN table_a.name, table_b.name)
```

and write table_c back to S3

I work mainly with spark so I can come up with some code fire up a cluster and do the join but I'm hoping for a more cost effective way. I looked at `presto`, `red shift` and `athena` but I'm unfamiliar with those services (maybe I'm even missing an option) and are wondering if there is something in the AWS ecosystem that can do that.

Comment: This sounds like a valid use case for Athena, since you already have formulated your query in SQL. Yet I have not tried queries within the Terabyte range, and sometimes Athena comes back with a message saying that its resources are exhausted. Yet I would definitely give it a try, since you will not need to set up a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Amazon Athena** is effectively a fully-managed Presto service. There is no need to create any infrastructure -- you just run commands in Athena and it runs on clusters behind-the-scenes. It is charged per TB read from disk, so Parquet files are an excellent way to reduce the amount of data that needs to be read.

Athena also stores the results of queries into S3, but it is not the same as storing output in an external table. Rather, you have to find the file where data was stored.

**Amazon Redshift** has a feature called **Spectrum** that does a very similar task, but has the overhead of running a Redshift cluster. This is good if you wish to join data from S3 and Redshift together, but not worth using if you *only* wish to access data stored in Amazon S3.

**Amazon S3** has a new feature called [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectSELECTContent.html) that can extract data from some file types (eg CSV), <strike>but not Parquet</strike>. Also, it doesn't seem to save the results back to S3.

**Amazon EMR** can provide a Hadoop cluster and you could use Spark or Hive to perform the operation. To keep this cost-effective, you could use **Spot instances**. Amazon EMR is now [charged per-second](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/amazon-emr-now-supports-per-second-billing/) so it can be very low-cost for small jobs. If you're comfortable with Spark, it's probably the best option for you.